# How to speed up base64 image fetch from MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a WebApi 2 in c# which returns item with their images from a database, the images are stored in another table with foreignkey on item. The issue is that some images are very large and my `API` take too long to make a `.GET` request which should return as fast as possible the content, the `SELECT` takes more than 3 second to be executed while the whole `.GET` request 3.77 seconds when query is cached.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID_MENU_PRP,
    ID_PLUREP,
    CODICE_PRP,
    DESC_S_PRP,
    UM_PRP,
    DESC_T_PRP,
    PRE_PRP,
    img.IMG_IMG
FROM
    vo_plurep plu
        INNER JOIN
    vo_images img ON plu.ID_PLUREP = img.ID_PLUREP_IMG
        AND img.ORDER_IMG = 0
WHERE
    plu.ATTIVO_PRP = 'True';
```

And `img.IMG_IMG` is a MEDIUMTEXT column

Here is the explain from the almost same query with a another JOIN to get proper data

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "621.57"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "plu",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "UNICA",
              "ID_MENU_PRP_idx",
              "ATTIVO_PRP_idx"
            ],
            "key": "ATTIVO_PRP_idx",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "ATTIVO_PRP"
            ],
            "key_length": "753",
            "ref": [
              "const"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 392,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 392,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "14.25",
              "eval_cost": "39.20",
              "prefix_cost": "53.45",
              "data_read_per_join": "7M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID_PLUREP",
              "ID_MENU_PRP",
              "MENU_PRP",
              "CODICE_PRP",
              "DESC_T_PRP",
              "DESC_S_PRP",
              "ATTIVO_PRP",
              "UM_PRP",
              "PRE_PRP"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`02288660356`.`plu`.`ID_MENU_PRP` is not null)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "menu",
            "access_type": "eq_ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY",
              "UNICA",
              "ID_CFG_MEN_idx"
            ],
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "ID_MENU"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "02288660356.plu.ID_MENU_PRP"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 392,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "98.00",
              "eval_cost": "39.20",
              "prefix_cost": "190.65",
              "data_read_per_join": "6M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID_MENU",
              "ID_CFG_MEN"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`02288660356`.`menu`.`ID_CFG_MEN` = 20)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "img",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "ID_PLUREP_IMG"
            ],
            "key": "ID_PLUREP_IMG",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "ID_PLUREP_IMG"
            ],
            "key_length": "5",
            "ref": [
              "02288660356.plu.ID_PLUREP"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 39,
            "filtered": "10.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "391.72",
              "eval_cost": "3.92",
              "prefix_cost": "621.57",
              "data_read_per_join": "30K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "ID_IMAGES",
              "ID_PLUREP_IMG",
              "IMG_IMG",
              "ORDER_IMG"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`02288660356`.`img`.`ORDER_IMG` = 0)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You can reduce the fetch size by 33% by skipping base64 and storing the images as `mediumbinary`. Otherwise, we need to see an `explain` for your query.

Comment: @Schwern just added the explain

Comment: Store the images on another server, actually designed for the task, then just serve the URLs from the DB through your API?

Comment: Why are they stored as base64? This is an overhead both ways in itself, in both space and time.

Comment: @MatBailie that what i would do, but my boss decided to store images as base64 in the DB

Comment: data_read_per_join: 6/7M for such a small query, this is really problematic. Your boss's design doesn't scale. The app server can easily run out of memory when concurrency is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading my Italian, `ATTIVO_PRP` is an "active" flag. And it's a string. I assume this is in every query. It's causing a filesort which can kill performance. Consider partitioning on `ATTIVO_PRP` to eliminate that performance problem. Also consider changing it to a `bit(1)` to save space.

The simplest fix is to store them as mediumbinary, not base64 encoded mediumtext. That will immediately reduce the amount of data you're retrieving by 33%, and eliminate having to post-process the result. You are reading a lot of data; that's the real problem.

The real fix, as folks have said in the comments, is to not serve static images out of a SQL database. Filesystems do that just fine. Store the images as static files, and only store the location and metadata in the database. Give the images unique names with [UUIDv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)). To avoid huge directories, which can be a performance problem, stripe the images into subdirectories 2 or 3 levels deep: `3/5/357d7070-bdc8-4577-9aeb-60a05a6a06b0.jpg`.

Your boss wants it as fast as possible, that's how you make it fast. If they're a good boss, they'll be happy with your optimization, or they'll explain why the images need to be in the database as basee64. If they're a bad boss... well, at least you know how to do it right for the next job.